# How to Unlink form created by others on my spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with permission "Anyone can Edit". Intentionally/unintentionally forms are created by users on my spreadsheet. Although I can manually unlink the forms, but there should be some way to do it through google script. I tried the following code, and though it works on the forms that are created by me, but not on those created by others.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheets = ss.getSheets()
for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)     
{
  var formurl = sheets[i].getFormUrl()
  if(formurl != null)
  {
    var formID = formurl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); 
    FormApp.openById(formID).removeDestination();    
  }
}
```

The script returns the following error:

```
  No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 14, file "Code")
```

Looking for solution.

Comment: Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: The above script now runs successfully. Seems the issue has been resolved.